# Spring MVC MongoDB integration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I would like to create Spring MVC sample with mongoDB by this tutorial http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/. I try @Autowired for `CustomerRepository repository` into my @Controller class, but I receive `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` for repository class member with exception message "....No matching bean of type [com.mvc.venko.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency..."

My @Controller class and CustomerRepository are in same package.

I can't get the problem causing this exception.

PS: using springFramework 3.1.1.RELEASE, spring-data-mongodb 1.4.2.RELEASE

EDIT: 
Complete conf.xml structure for resolving problem. Please switch to Spring 3.2.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.mvc.venko" />
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" write-concern="NONE" />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't configure a bean of CustomerRepository type.
You can do this with this line in your spring-config.xml:

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="/path to your repository package/" />
```

more docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances)